How to remove the animated tick with FormBuilderChipOption using flutter_form_builder in Flutter?
Is it possible to remove the animated tick that appears with FormBuilderChoiceChip using the flutter_form_builder package? I can't see any properties to allow this, and wonder if there is a work around (that involves keep using this package)?
 FormBuilderChoiceChip(
                  initialValue: 'multi',
                  name: 'choices',
                  options: [
                    FormBuilderChipOption(
                      avatar: SizedBox.shrink(),
                      value: 'multi',
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                          'Multi-choice',
                        )),
                      ),
                    ),

                    /// etc
                  ],
                ),




I dont think it is possible as of now. I would be nice to have showCheckmark property as this pull request proposed. maybe it will be available in near future.

You can use this parameter in FormBuilderChoiceChip
showCheckmark: false,


Yes, now this works properly
